# passing name parameter through form using jquery

Tags: jquery, forms

I have a website with multiple pages using the same form in footer. The footer is included through php, so it's the same on every page. I want to identify the page which message was sent from.

So basically on every page I specify the page-id parameter (thought the  would be a good idea?):

```
<a class="page-id" name="page-a"></a>
```

then in footer inside the actual form I will get a hidden input field with auto-filled value of "page-a" defined on the actual page:

```
 <input class="which-page" type="text" value="">
```

so I want the input to look like this after auto-implenentation of the value:

```
 <input class="which-page" type="text" value="page-a">
```

I was trying to use jquery to implement this dynamically, but I'm not very good at it. Here is what I have.

```
  $pageid = $('.page-id').find('name').clone().text('');
  $('.which-page').find('value').contents().wrap($pageid);
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tucado/5pL360s4/12/)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `attr()` for the name attribute  and `val()` to set value of the `<input>`

```js
$pageid = $('.page-id').attr('name');
$('.which-page').val($pageid);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="page-id" name="page-a"></a>
<input class="which-page" type="text" value="">
```